# Gets posts_per_page via $_COOKIE

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, setcookie

I seem to not be able to understand why a) my variable is not being returned within the page and, b) why there seems to be a cookie set for each individual page.

**AIM:**

In a product listing, I have the option to filter results by (small numbers for this example) 5, 10, or all. When I paginate the `$_COOKIE` resets to the default value, and once set is set for that page. I can alternate between page 1 and page 2 with different listings of results.

**File "cookies.php" (before `<!doctype html>`):**

```
<?php $post_per_page = $_POST['post_per_page'];
    if (isset($post_per_page)) {
        // Store it in the cookie
        setcookie('post_per_page', $post_per_page, time()+60*60*24, "/");
        // And save in a variable
        $postsperpage = $post_per_page;
    }

    // Then check existing cookies
    else if (isset($_COOKIE['post_per_page'])) {
        $postsperpage = $_COOKIE['post_per_page'];
    }

    // Finally use a default value if none was set
    else {
        // Default to 3 for example:
        $postsperpage = 3;
    }
?>
```

**Within my taxonomy.php:**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         =>      'product',
    'posts_per_page'    =>      $postsperpage,
    'paged'             =>      $paged
);
```

In this the `$postsperpage` is empty, not even returning the default "3" from the `cookies.php`. So I have to recall the contents of `cookies.php` commenting out the `setcookie` line.

**Markup:**

```
<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="post_per_page" value="5">5</button>
    <button type="submit" name="post_per_page" value="10">10</button>
    <button type="submit" name="post_per_page" value="-1">ALL</button>
</form>
```

---

## **EDIT**

Somehow the cookie setting has fixed itself up. But I am still confused why I have to include the `cookies.php` contents into the taxonomy rather than its initial variable setting being global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless these php files are being included on the same page, the $postsperpage variable doesn't exist on taxonomy.php. If that is the case, you should just retrieve the cookie value on that page like so...

```
$postsperpage = $_COOKIE['post_per_page'];
```

Comment: Okay that was what I was expecting. So I remove everything from cookies.php except the setting of the cookie and then have the variable setting in the taxonomy.php the variable doesnt update until the next refresh. Any way to make it update immediately?

Comment: Could you explain how these files are being loaded? Is one being included in the other, or are you actually navigating to each of them ?

Comment: Using Roots Wordpress Theme (https://github.com/retlehs/roots): There is a base.php file that calls for the correct template file depending on what type of item you're calling (page, post, custom). Above the beginning of base.php there I call (like `include()`) the cookies.php file. Then in the loop of calling the correct template part it eventually gets to taxonomy.php

Comment: Figured it out myself with the aid of you SomeSillyName.